# How to cancel `request.Cancel()` During `appWillterminate` in AlamoFire?

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift4

I am trying to save the downloaded data in download failure case

```
            switch response.result{
        case .success( _):
            print("success response")
            break
        case .failure( _):
            print("error")
            if let resumeData = response.resumeData{
                self.resumeData = resumeData
                Shared.dataCache.set(value: resumeData, key: self.keyResumeData)
            }
        }
```

When I trigger `request.Cancel()` using button press event its working perfectly. But when I trigger the same function during `appWillTerminate` its not getting into failure case. Is there any way to save downloaded data during App Termination using **Alamofire**

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work for you:

```
 URLSession.shared.getAllTasks(){
            tasks in
            tasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
        }
```